# Upload xml file to root of Wordpress app hosted in Openshift

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift, bing

While verifying the ownership of my domain www.chansek.com, I found Bing Webmaster Tools telling to upload BingSiteAuth.xml file to root of my web app.

How do I do that? My site is hosted in Openshift through an WordPress app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install [Bing Webmastertools Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/verify-bing-webmaster-tools/) and open plugin page from Settings menu on admin panel. Copy/Paste Bing verification code to Plugin input textbox like below and Save;

[image]